# react-widgets: what to return from onSearch (Multiselect)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to use react-widgets with `onSearch` with `Multiselect`. I can see that `onSearch` gets called with `searchTerm`. But, the response never becomes part of the options/data for `Multiselect`.

I've tried returning the results in an Array or in an object with the key `data` to the Array.

```
const getOptions = searchTerm => {
  return [{ _id: 1, username: 'Bob' }];
}

const TagItem = ({ username }) => <span>{username}</span>

const MultiSelectUsers = ({ input, ...rest }) =>
  <Multiselect {...input}
    onBlur={() => input.onBlur()}
    value={input.value || []}
    valueField="_id"
    tagComponent={TagItem}
    itemComponent={TagItem}
    onSearch={getOptions}
    {...rest}
  />
```

Bonus: How do I use onSearch with Promise?

Comment: You need to re-render the component with the updated data.  Remember that it is considered an anti-pattern in React for a component manage itself.  If returning something in `onSearch` updated the Multiselect component, then the component would be managing itself, outside of React.  What you need to do in your `onSearch` is update the `data` property of the Multiselect component and re-render the application.

Comment: Thanks kevin628,

I've tried hooking up `getOptions` to change state in `MultiSelectUsers` and pass that down to `Multiselect` via `data`, but it appears to not update `Multiselect`. Is there a way to force a child component to update upon newProps?

Comment: Your `getOptions` implementation needs to re-render the application using React.  Is that happening in `getOptions`?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things need to happen here.

1) `onSearch` merely calls a callback, ie, it updates nothing. The update needs to be done via `data`. (Eg, use state in `MultiSelectUsers`)

2) The trick is that #1 won't work, unless you set `filter={false}` in `Multiselect`